# Real-time graphing application for SQL data

Tags: charts, sql, real-time

I am looking for a free data graphing application that can pull data from MySQL and display it on a trend graph without any programming. It should use a GUI to select the data to be plotted, start time, end time etc.  Ideally it could be historical data or live real-time data.

- [LiveGraph](http://live-graph.org/) looks like it has all the features but it works with CSV data
- [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) is similar but it requires the data to be in [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/)

Is there anything similar that is designed to retrieve data from a SQL database?

Comment: What is your price range? ... Or free?

Comment: Yes, Free.  Prefer open source but not required.  Modified original question

Comment: How about excel?  You could set up an odbc data source and suck the data into excel for graphing

Comment: As BrianAdkins mentioned, Excel is probably your best option, if you have it?

Comment: I would rather not use Excel.  I am leaning toward setting up something that dumps the DB table to a CSV file and then use LiveGraph

Comment: I found one more option, http://kst-plot.kde.org/  it supports multiple file formats but not SQL.  But it does have a plugin capability to add other file types.

Comment: And one more http://labplot.sourceforge.net/  It does have a import from SQL function but still can't plot SQL data in real-time.

Answer (score 5):

Simple and free real time charts for Windows/Mac/Linux: **[sqlDashboards](http://www.sqldashboards.com/help/video-tutorial/kdb-database-live-charting). Connects to mysql/postgresql/mssql**, allows heatmaps, bar charts, area charts, pie charts.. plotted straight from SQL queries and refreshed in real time.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to see animation)</sup>

Charts are generated straight from SQL as soon as you write the query. No delay, no complicated setup. Configuring the layout is drag-and-drop.

Disclaimer: I work for the company but I believe it fits exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: The "free" version is just a demo that does not let you save your dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I use tableau for BI data visualization, but it ain't cheap.  However, it could work for your purposes, and they have a free trial.

http://www.tableausoftware.com/tableau-software

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with Tableau but was looking for something simple and free.

Answer (score 0):

What about Stack Exchange's own [Data Explorer](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/)?