# MySQL Data Visualization

Tags: software-rec, mysql, data-visualization

I love data. I love watching it flow in and I love real time stats. I have a huge database for a webapp I recently created that is getting hit with a few hundred write queries per minute. Is there any existing solution out there that will help me visualize that in real time with some kind of counter or scrolling feed of what is being added to the database in real time? I dev on an Ubuntu machine but my primary is OS X, so either works.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/449780/real-time-graphing-application-for-sql-data

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RTView](http://www.sl.com/products/rtview.shtml). You may need to write some custom code, and it is not a free product.

Answer (score 0):

Real Time Database visualization:
http://sqldashboards.com/database/h2-real-time-stock-charts

It

- Works with a number of databases including MySQL
- Cross-platform (java)
- Free version allows all chart types and customization but not saving

disclaimer: I own the company making the software and write some of the code. :)
but I do believe it's the best tool for real-time data visualization with a good free offering.